# Server side script in laravel 5 that counts down time when zero then notify to client

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, server, real-time

I am new to laravel

Detailed explanation:
I am creating quiz contest website.I have a timer in which user have to answer if not answered then gets eliminated.
And every quiz contest have three rounds.After that final results are complied .

I need timer count down on server side when time goes to zero then notify to client that time is zero.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: you shuld use javascript setTimeOut function to implement this,sever side only need give a start time and when user ansewer quiz server siede check if current time is valid.

Comment: hm that i good logic but i want to implement this logic for min 250 users and max 1000.and max limit may be increase.
if i do this then min 250 requests goes to server and max 1000.
is there any background service on server side in laravel?
i am using windows 8.1 with xampp .